# Unity3D: How to make a glowing gradient sphere?

Tags: unity-game-engine, model, light, emit

[image: target]

So I need a glowing sphere with a halo of light, which casts light on a near objects. Also, as you see on the image, sphere must have a gradient.

I'm using 2 spheres and point of light at the moment. And I really don't like the results:
[image: bad results]

- There is no gradient at all
- I need to use second Point Light to cast light to near objects

So... is there any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have **two needs**,

(1) the **"actual" light** which casts a light on nearby objects.

(So, I mean that is literally a UnityEngine.Light http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Light.html )

(2) Separately, you need (basically) **a "glowing orb"** that looks like the white and yellow thing in your image.

These two things are completely separate.

## You should indeed do them separately.

---

Now regarding "2" how to make a glow, that's called a "bloom". There is a lot to look in to but this will probably do it for you:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/914945/what-replaces-the-glow-effect-in-unity-5.html

[image]

Note that getting a good glow **is not that easy**.

Here's a really great asset, that's actually free for goodness sake,

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/28044

you should surely get that to experiment with at first.  There are other well-known assets as well, like https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/8238

Be sure to google for [many QA](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/571510/view.html) on the glow topic.

Comment: the actual answer to your question here is, "You should indeed do them separately." - that's the "secret" to what your'e up to.  Regarding putting a glow on an object. It's a big topic and there are various approaches. I gave you a number of approaches to look in to. you'd probably have to ask new specific questions about details of any of those you know?

Comment: The problem is - I need to place this sphere in the another half transparent sphere. And then bloom stops working. I need to do this firslty because center of the first sphere is too bright. And second: this is an idea...

Comment: And how to use MK Glow and Unity Bloom together? They both requiring material.

Comment: looking forward to your new question @user64675